# SSH Connection Timeout on GCP using Paramiko

Tags: ssh, sftp, paramiko, google-cloud-composer, vpc

I am trying to push a file via SFTP from GCP to an external server using paramiko in Cloud Composer. Below is a sample of the code:

```
    import paramiko

    host, port = "hostname", 22
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    username, password = "username", "password"

    transport.banner_timeout = 100

    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    if sftp:
        sftp.close()

    if transport:
        transport.close()
```

When I run this code on GCP I get the following error

```
raise socket.timeout()\nsocket.timeout\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/script.py", line 25, in <module>\n    res = make_sftp_connectors(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/script.py", line 16, in make_sftp_connectors\n    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1178, in connect\n    self.start_client()\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 550, in start_client\n    raise e\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1904, in run\n    self._check_banner()\n  File "/tmp/venvuuscmldg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2054, in _check_banner\n    \'Error reading SSH protocol banner\' + str(e)\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner\n'
```

I have tried increasing the timeout but nothing changes and it looks like it is a connection issue between GCP and the external server. Is it due to restrictions in egress connections from GCP (e.g. VPC, Firewall rules) by default?

Comment: Could you try referring to this [github link](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/673) for this error raised in Paramiko as it is a known Issue. Also could you try upgrading to paramiko 2.1.1 as it appears to have resolved the paramiko issues.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was there was a firewall rule in the GCP that prohibited connecting to the external server's IP address.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Where did you change the firewall setting in GCP? Thanks